# Question about repeated quotient groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, ideals, quotient-spaces

I was wondering if there was a simpler representation for the quotient group
$(K[x,y]/\langle xy\rangle)/\langle x, y-1\rangle$. Where $K[x,y]$ is the polynomial ring with variables $x,y$ over the field $K$. I was thinking that maybe it's the same as the quotient group $K[x,y]/\langle xy,x,y-1\rangle$, since mapping an element in $K[x,y]$ to the first quotient group will remove any multiples of $xy$, and the second quotient group mapping will map the new element to one without any multiples of the ideal $\langle x, y-1\rangle$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the quotient can be simplified as you wrote because of the third isomorphism theorem.

Moreover, $(xy,x,y-1)=(x,y-1)$ so we can write it as $K[x,y]/(x,y-1)$. By the first isomorphism theorem, this is essentially the image of the map $K[x,y]\to K$ which evaluates $x$ at the value $0$ and evaluates $y$ at the value $1$. IOW, the quotient is $\cong K$ itself.

Comment: I just learnt the third isomorphism theorem, can you please state explicitly how the quotient can be simplified using the third isomorphism theorem

Comment: Also is the map you've defined basically saying that, $\psi:K[x,y]\rightarrow K$, e.g. $\psi(3x+5y+2xy)=3(0)+5(1)+2(0)(1)=5$

Comment: By the FIT, $K[x,y]/Ker(\psi)\cong im(\psi)$, but how is $ker(\psi)=\langle x, y-1\rangle$ and how do we know the map is surjective, i.e $im(\psi)=K$

Comment: I'm sorry if my questions seem trivial

Comment: @Andrew Having trivial questions is not a problem. **Not trying** to figure out the answers to your questions can be a problem. Have you *tried* thinking about your questions? Applying the 3rd iso theorem is essentially plugging the things you have at hand into the theorem - can you not figure out what the ring and the two ideals are in your problem? Have you *tried* showing every element of $K$ is in the image of the homomorphism I defined? Have you *tried* showing that if $f(0,1)=0$ then $f(x,y)$ is a multiple of $x$ plus a multiple of $y-1$?